# mysql error when comparing date (php)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am not sure why this i get this mysql error. Originally i didnt have '' around the date. Then i tried ''' and '`' without any luck. Whats wrong?

```
SELECT COUNT(user) WHERE user=1 AND pass_time<'2009-09-21 13:44:38';


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user=1 AND pass_time<'2009-09-21 13:44:38''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the table where you select from. E.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(user) FROM my_table WHERE ...
```

Comment: I think I can see you blushing from here